# Using PUT method to update existing Article in external database

Tags: javascript, json, rest, put

So to cut long story short, we are Using restdb.io on a school project to practice our "back-end" skills. We are supposed to build a simple website which will allow us to post new articles, delete existing articles and (my focus point) edit existing articles. We are using the `POST` method for the new Articles and `PUT` method for the edit. Because I don't understand the nature of the `PUT` method, I am simply using it in the same manner as the `POST` method

```
    document.querySelector('button[name="save-edit"]').addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let userTitle = document.querySelector('input[name="title"]');
        let userDate = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
        let userContent = document.querySelector('textarea[name="content"]');
        let data = {
            title: userTitle.value,
            content: userContent.value,
            date: userDate.value
        };


        let postData = JSON.stringify(articleData);
        fetch("https://someRandomDatabase.restdb.io/rest/articles/" + articleData._id, {
                method: "put",
                headers: myHeaders,
                body: postData
            })
            .then(d => d.json())
            .then(t => {
                console.log(t);
                document.querySelector("#modal").style.left = "100vw";

                document.querySelector('input[name="title"]').value = "";
                document.querySelector('input[type="date"]').value = "";
                document.querySelector('textarea[name="content"]').value = "";
                showArticle(data);
                document.querySelector('button[name="save-edit"]').disabled = true;
            });
    });
});
```

This is the entire piece of code that takes care of the editing UX function of the website (main part starting with fetching the data). Now because I don't have that much theory regarding the `PUT` and all the articles I found on the Internet are just `POST` vs `PUT`, I am not sure where It's wrong. In it's current state It just adds new Article to the database (so basically just like `POST` method) instead of editing the one I clicked on.

PS: this piece of code is actually inside a function called `showArticle()`, which is dedicated to posting a new article. The reason I put in is that I am passing along the id of the Article (thus the content)

Comment: Typically, with an Update form, you're going to want to have a hidden field which contains ```id``` or some other identifier for the ```model``` (article in your case) being edited, the ```id``` then gets passed along with the put request, where the server then can find and update correct record

Comment: Ah, ignore me, according to restdb.io, id is passed along with the url.. question: where is ```articleData``` defined?

Comment: Does `articleData` contain an id? Typically with a PUT you would only send the data that's changed.

Comment: articleData is defined in the function called showArticle that puts the content of the articles on the page to the cloned template